# What other online descriptions exist for specific game engines 8-bit and 16-bit game engines?

Tags: game-design

[I found a good description of the engine in the Sonic games](http://info.sonicretro.org/Sonic_Physics_Guide). It describes roughly how the engine works for people writing their own clones. In my case, I am simply interested in getting a general view of how the many 8-bit and 16-bit game engines worked on their respective consoles.

What other online descriptions exist for specific game engines 8-bit and 16-bit game engines?

Comment: The only sonic description I remember was one that didn't describe the 'engine', but did describe how the in game physics worked.   Can you link to the article you're thinking of so people can have a better understanding of what you're talking about?

Comment: We didn't really have game engines back then. We just had games. Sometimes you'd take a previous game and replace bits of it to make a new game, but calling it an engine is a bit of a stretch. Given that almost all games back then ran on predictable hardware with single-threaded execution 99% of them would look much like `int main() { while(1) { read_input(); update_world(); render_screen() } (or the assembly equivalent), so it's hard to know what you're asking for.

Comment: Perhaps we need a definition of "game engine" for clarity.  The term "game engine" gives me the impression that there's a generalized underlying system of some sort that one or more games rely on to function.  Being [assumedly] modular, I'd also wonder if this "engine" could be updated separately to install performance improvements, independent of game updates.

Comment: As @Kylotan pointed out. Engine is Input, Processing, Output. Processing was some hacked up physics. Input was polling or whatever hardware allowed; Output the same. That is not interesting, but what is extremely interesting is how they managed to make it so small&efficient, that is what I value about it. You may be interested in [making Allegro game in 20 lines](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/237297), it contains many hacks to make code small; thought some of them are C language related, some - like how they use arrays ... - are worth knowing I think.

Comment: @RandolfRichardson "Generalized" / "modular" tends to have a runtime cost. Things were tailored exactly to spec back then, nothing more and nothing less, given the need to squeeze out every ounce of CPU power.

Answer (score 10):

Most games of that era functioned very uniquely; there was very little engine-like code reuse.

That said, you're fairly likely to find the kind of detailed descriptions of gameplay mechanics you want from games that are very big/popular like [Metroid](http://www.metroid-database.com/m1/sourcecode.php), [Final Fantasy 6](http://masterzed.cavesofnarshe.com/ff3.html) or [Final Fantasy Tactics](http://www.ffhacktics.com/) -- people have been researching the mechanics of those games extensively and you can find a fair bit of information about them scattered arond. Also games that are popular among [tool-assist speed run](http://tasvideos.org/GameResources.html) fans as they tend to have know (and thus, hopefully document) a lot of the interesting quirks of the game code used in the games they run.

(Note that the TASVideos link was being really flaky at the time I wrote this and may not connect reliably.)

Answer (score 6):

There is [commented data formats with little code of several 8-bit games](http://www.icemark.com/dataformats/), these games are:

- Lords of Midnight
- Doomdark's Revenge
- The Hobbit
- Manic Miner
- Jet Set Willy
- Jet Set Willy 2
- Atic Atac
- Knight Lore
- Alien 8
- Sabre Wulf
- Wanted: Monty Mole
- Nodes of Yesod
- Dynamite Dan
- Starquake
- Ant Attack
- PAW
- Driller

I found it interesting that some of them use compression (RLE, dictionary), some of them don't, some use name generators; they had to save space because 8-bit computers had little memory. I believe that by examining these data formats You can derive algorithms yourself. :)

There is more 1 hour long video of making of Google's Pacman clone on Youtube and they used this [detailed study of Pacman](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3938/the_pacman_dossier.php?print=1) (Gamasutra link). In video they talk how they used some "good old" techniques like packing multiple textures into one ...